# Save a contact after app launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I don't know if this is possible.

I want to save a number after launching the app in the first view(Of course prompting the user).
This will be used when sending a message directly from the app.

Anyone tried doing this?

Comment: Try using NSUserDefaults

Comment: @iBradApps NSUserDefaults cannot interact with the contacts database.

Comment: Oh sorry, I might have misread the question! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this by utilizing the [Address Book UI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html) framework in conjunction with the [Address Book](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html) framework. The Address Book UI framework facilitates the displaying, editing, selecting, and creating of records in the Address Book database, and uses the Address Book framework in the background.

So in your case, you'd launch the Address Book UI on startup.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this! Now I know there's a framework for this like the music library.

Comment: Oh. Another thing, Can I directly set the "To" field from my app pulling the saved contact?

Comment: @zeekerg Are you talking about mail or contacts?

Comment: @zeekerg I'm not completely sure what "to" field is in the contacts app.

Comment: I mean, can I get the saved contact and have it automatically as a recipient so that the user don't have to search in the contacts and only just press "Send" directly?

Comment: I believe so. I'll get back to you on that later. I'm late for something right now. SOrry.